# Reference of function

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to make a reference of function in JavaScript to the obfuscate of source code

```
var g = document.getElementById;
```

but the call `g('id')` causes an error in Google Chrome `TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The context of the function call must be the document. Use

```
var g = document.getElementById.bind(document);
```

If you want to be compatible with IE8 (which doesn't have [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)), use

```
var g = function(id){
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```